# ng-hide or ng-show does not work if its controlled from within a ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-show, ng-hide

I am trying to hide the div if any of the buttons in the ng-repeat is clicked. However it doesn't seem to work, it leads me to think if ng-hide or ng-show won't work if it is controlled from within a ng-repeat?

```
<div data-ng-hide="showChooseHardware">
    <table class="table">
        <tbody>
            <tr data-ng-repeat="hardware in hardwares">
                <td>{{hardware.name}}</td>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" class="btn" data-ng-click="showChooseHardware=!showChooseHardware"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the fact that ng-repeat creates a new scope for each template and due to how prototypal inheritance works in JavaScript (and AngularJS).

Use an object:

```
$scope.viewModel = { showChooseHardware: false };
```

HTML:

```
data-ng-hide="viewModel.showChooseHardware"
```

And:

```
data-ng-click="viewModel.showChooseHardware=!viewModel.showChooseHardware"
```

A great explanation on the issue can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14049482/2887841).

*I recommend using `ng-show`instead in this case since the variable is called `showChooseHardware`.*

Comment: Thanks, your explanation works. Reason why i used showChooseHardware with ng-hide was due to debugging, i was trying out both ng-show and ng-hide to see if ng-show was a problem. I reverted back to ng-show now. Now, i need to read the referenced link.. TY!

Comment: A simple and effective way to avoid scope inheritance issues is to use controllerAs syntax. `ng-controller="MyController as ctrl" ng-model="ctrl.showChooseHardware"`

Answer (score 1):

ngRepeat directive creates new scope in every iteration,for every item in array.It can make a problem,which you have.